# Problema con form Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, div

Tengo 2 campos de formulario que son 2 input text. Uno hace como de prefijo del nombre y el otro es el nombre.

Este es el aspecto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesita es quitarel espacio que hay entre el primer input text (el deshabilitado) y el segundo, ya que la función de estos dos es que el primero sirva como prefijo al segundo.

Quiero que quede una cosa así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta hecho todo con Bootstrap. Mi pregunta es si hay alguna forma de hacerlo con Bootstrap.

Mi código:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-3" id="hideDiv">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="prefijoAlmacen" type="text" id="general-text" name="general-text" class="form-control" value="" disabled />
        <span class="mensajeErrorNombre"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="modalNombre" type="text" id="general-text" name="general-text" class="form-control" value="" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
    </div>
</div>
```

He probado a poner otro div row dentro de la columna, pero nada; he probado a poner los 2 inputs dentro  del mismo, pero tampoco funciona...

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veo que estás usando `Bootstrap 3.x` entonces deberías crear unas clases de ayudas (`helper class`).

Te he creado 2:

1. Para quitar el `padding` de la **izquierda** en cuando tenga la clase `col-*`:

```
div[class*='col-'].p-l-0 {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

2. Para quitar el `padding` de la **derecha** en cuando tenga la clase `col-*`:

```
div[class*='col-'].p-r-0 {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

Veamos las clases en acción:

```css
div[class*='col-'].p-l-0 {
  padding-left: 0;
}

div[class*='col-'].p-r-0 {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-3 p-r-0" id="hideDiv">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="prefijoAlmacen" type="text" id="general-text" name="general-text" class="form-control" value="" disabled />
        <span class="mensajeErrorNombre"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 p-l-0">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="modalNombre" type="text" id="general-text" name="general-text" class="form-control" value="" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
    </div>
</div>
```

Nota: Si no quieres que este tan pegado, creas simplemente más clases con los `paddings` deseados.